# adding elements into the doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

this is my code for main class and doubly linked class and node class but when I run the program ,in the concole will show this"datastructureproject.DoublyLinkedList@19ee1ac" instead of the random numbers .please help me thanks!

main class:

```
    public class Main {

    public static int getRandomNumber(double min, double max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return (int) (random.nextDouble() * (max - min) + min);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j;
        int i = 0;
        i = getRandomNumber(10, 10000);
        DoublyLinkedList listOne = new DoublyLinkedList();

        for (j = 0; j <= i / 2; j++) {
            listOne.add(getRandomNumber(10, 10000));


        }
        System.out.println(listOne);

    }
}
```

doubly linked list class:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {

private Node head ;
private Node tail;
private long size = 0;

public DoublyLinkedList() {
    head= new Node(0, null, null);
    tail = new Node(0, head, null);
}



public void add(int i){

head.setValue(i);
Node newNode = new Node();
head.setNext(newNode);
newNode.setPrev(head);
newNode = head;

}
public  String toString() {
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
result.append("(head) - ");
Node temp = head;
while (temp.getNext() != tail) {
    temp = temp.getNext();
    result.append(temp.getValue() + " - ");
}
result.append("(tail)");
    return result.toString();
}
  }
```

and the node class is like the class that you have seen before (Node prev,Node next,int value)

edited: I have added toString method but will show null pointer exception for line "result.append(temp.getValue() + " - ");" please help me thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you call `System.out.println` on an object it (kindly) calls the `toString` method of that object. If you haven't defined a `toString` for an object you will get the one defined by one of it's ancestors. In your case you aren't extending anything, so you will get the toString of `Object` - probably not what you want.

Try defining a toString() method in your class. In it you should probably loop over the nodes and build a `String` containing the required representation.

Comment: hi I have used to String method
but now it will show an exception null pointer exception

Comment: That exception is fired when you try to do something with a null object. My best guess is that the add method is incorrect and `temp` becomes `null` at some point, instead of becoming `tail`

Answer (score 1):

When you print the object, it executes it's .toString() method.
What you see is the default toString implementation.

You can override .toString to customize what get's printed - in your case, you'd probably loop over the items and create a comma-separated list of the numbers or something

Answer (score 0):

running `System.out.println(Object);` will need to convert `Object` into a string. It does this by executing the `toString` method. If an object has not implemented `toString` the default implementation is used which returns the class name and its hashcode.

you will need to either override the object and supply a suitable `toString` or loop through the elements and build your string prior to calling `println` yourself.